# Фильтрация в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

На форме расположены Edit1 и DBLookupComboBox1, DBGrid. При нажатии на кнопку, нужно чтобы работала фильтрация по этим полям (таблицы разные). Есть SQL-запрос. Пока что только такой код написала, но не работает

> Ошибка [Error] Unit2.pas(380): Missing operator or semicolon

```
ADOQuery1.Filtered:=false;
ADOQuery1.Filter:='name:= '''+DBLookupComboBox1.Text+''' and 'fio= '''+Edit1.Text+''';
ADOQuery1.Filtered:=true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательнее с кавычками и не жалейте пробелов.

```
ADOQuery1.Filter := 'name = ''' + DBLookupComboBox1.Text + ''' ' + 
                ' and fio = ''' + Edit1.Text + ''' ';
```